# Are all rows per group equal to ...?

Tags: pandas

I need to make sure all rows per id are equal to `"red"` to distinguish id 1 from id 2:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"id":[1,1,1,2,2,2],
        "status":["red","red","red","green","red","red"]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
   # id status
   # 1    red
   # 1    red
   # 1    red
   # 2  green
   # 2    red
   # 2    red


df[df.loc[df["status"]=="red"].groupby("id").size() / df.groupby("id").status.size()==1]
#IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

#It is enough if the output is 
#   a series/list/array of the ids where all rows are red.
all_rows_are_red = [1]
```

Comment: If you need to ensure that all rows are red, just assign red, no? `df['status'] = 'red'`. If you just want to check `df['status'].eq('red').all()` -> `False`

Comment: @BERA I see, this wasn't clear to me, see below then ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the IDs with only "red", you can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
out = df[df['status'].eq('red').groupby(df['id']).transform('all')]
```

Variant:

```
keep = df['status'].eq('red').groupby(df['id']).all()

out = df[df['id'].isin(keep[keep].index)]
```

Output:

```
   id status
0   1    red
1   1    red
2   1    red
```

Intermediates:

```
df['is_red'] = df['status'].eq('red')
df['all_red'] = df.groupby('id')['is_red'].transform('all')

   id status  is_red  all_red
0   1    red    True     True
1   1    red    True     True
2   1    red    True     True
3   2  green   False    False
4   2    red    True    False
5   2    red    True    False
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all groups if only `red`, in my solution remove groups if at least one non red `status` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
out = df[~df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['status'].ne('red'),'id'])]
print (out)
   id status
0   1    red
1   1    red
2   1    red
```

How it working:

```
#get groups with non red values
print (df.loc[df['status'].ne('red'),'id'])
3    2
Name: id, dtype: int64

#filter out non red ids
print (~df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['status'].ne('red'),'id']))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

If need all `id` with `red` only use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
out = np.setdiff1d(df['id'], df.loc[df['status'].ne('red'),'id']).tolist()
print (out)
[1]
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, I need some help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77987920/pandas-explode-a-list-of-nested-dictionaries-column-and-append-as-new-rows). Can you please have a look?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - ouch, loops in pandas, not easy, I think accepted answer is nice solution.