# Pandas: Explode a list of nested dictionaries column and append as new rows

Tags: python, pandas, nested

Please consider the below dict for example:

```
d2 = [{'event_id': 't1',
  'display_name': 't1',
  'form_count': 0,
  'repetition_id': None,
  'children': [{'event_id': 't_01',
    'display_name': 't(1)',
    'form_count': 1,
    'repetition_id': 't1',
    'children': [],
    'forms': [{'form_id': 'f1',
      'form_repetition_id': '1',
      'form_name': 'fff1',
      'is_active': True,
      'is_submitted': False}]}],
  'forms': []},
 {'event_id': 't2',
  'display_name': 't2',
  'form_count': 0,
  'repetition_id': None,
  'children': [{'event_id': 't_02',
    'display_name': 't(2)',
    'form_count': 1,
    'repetition_id': 't2',
    'children': [{'event_id': 't_03',
      'display_name': 't(3)',
      'form_count': 1,
      'repetition_id': 't3',
      'children': [],
      'forms': [{'form_id': 'f3',
        'form_repetition_id': '1',
        'form_name': 'fff3',
        'is_active': True,
        'is_submitted': False}]}],
    'forms': [{'form_id': 'f2',
      'form_repetition_id': '1',
      'form_name': 'fff2',
      'is_active': True,
      'is_submitted': False}]}],
  'forms': []}]
```

Above `d2` is a list of dicts, where `children` is a nested dict with same keys as the parent.

Also, `children` can have nesting upto multiple levels which is not possible to know upfront. So in short, I don't know how many times to keep exploding it.

Current df:

```
In [54]: df11 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

In [55]: df11
Out[55]: 
  event_id display_name  form_count repetition_id                                           children forms
0       t1           t1           0          None  [{'event_id': 't_01', 'display_name': 't(1)', ...    []
1       t2           t2           0          None  [{'event_id': 't_02', 'display_name': 't(2)', ...    []
```

I want to flatten it in the below way.

**Expected output**:

```
 event_id display_name  form_count repetition_id                                           children                                              forms
0       t1           t1           0          None  {'event_id': 't_01', 'display_name': 't(1)', '...                                                 []
1       t2           t2           0          None  {'event_id': 't_02', 'display_name': 't(2)', '...                                                 []
0     t_01         t(1)           1            t1                                                 []  [{'form_id': 'f1', 'form_repetition_id': '1', ...
1     t_02         t(2)           1            t2  {'event_id': 't_03', 'display_name': 't(3)', ...  [{'form_id': 'f2', 'form_repetition_id': '1', ...
0     t_03         t(3)           0            t3                                                 []     [{'form_id': 'f2', 'form_repetition_id': '1'}]
```

How do I know that how many nested children are there?

My attempt:

```
In [58]: df12 = df11.explode('children')
In [64]: final = pd.concat([df12, pd.json_normalize(df12.children)])
In [72]: final
Out[72]: 
  event_id display_name  form_count repetition_id                                           children                                              forms
0       t1           t1           0          None  {'event_id': 't_01', 'display_name': 't(1)', '...                                                 []
1       t2           t2           0          None  {'event_id': 't_02', 'display_name': 't(2)', '...                                                 []
0     t_01         t(1)           1            t1                                                 []  [{'form_id': 'f1', 'form_repetition_id': '1', ...
1     t_02         t(2)           1            t2  [{'event_id': 't_03', 'display_name': 't(3)', ...  [{'form_id': 'f2', 'form_repetition_id': '1', ...
```

Comment: Is the column(s) with the nested levels always named "children"? If not is there a way to identify it/them?

Comment: @mozway It'll always be named `children`.

Comment: sorry I was AFK. I would use a recursive approach for that, I see that there is a nice answer that does that below ;)

Comment: @mozway No problem. I agree that the recursive approach is good. I was wondering if there's a Pandas solution for this?

Comment: Honestly, I think a pandas solution would also need recursion and be likely less efficient. When there is no direct vectorized approach, pure python is often better than pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved with a little bit of recursive programming:

```py
from collections import deque

queue = deque(d2)
d3 = []

while queue:
    item = queue.popleft()
    d3.append(item)

    # Optionally add a parent_event_id. Remove if you don't need it.
    queue += [
        {**child, "parent_event_id": item["event_id"]}
        for child in item.get("children", [])
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(d3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1 . Just wondering if there's a way to solve this in pure Pandas?

Comment: you could use `pd.json_normalize(()` but you would still need the loop(s)

Comment: No pandas solution can accommodate the arbitrary nesting